# What to do when receiving an unsuitable but still relevant answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, advice

On the 28$^{\textrm{th}}$ of June, I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842710/when-do-n2-points-in-mathbbrn-lies-on-a-same-n-1-sphere) on the main site which has soon received an answer proposal; even though the concerned input is certainly relevant to my question as it provides a different insight on the matter, this is in any way an answer to my question. Indeed, I feel like I narrowed the framework of my question with some really specific restrictions that the answer received does not at all fit in. While I did not accept their answer and explain to them why I won't, some users may think that my question is settled. Therefore, my question may not receive any accurate answer; this raises the following questions:

- When receiving an unsuitable but still relevant answer, what should the original poster do to keep interest in their question?
- Is it acceptable to mention in the title that the question is still in need of an answer yet it has apparently already one?
- What can I do to avoid receiving that kind of answers in the future? Was my question unclear?

Don't get me wrong, if you find that I kind of sound salty, I am not that upset with the answer I received; I am really just seeking an accurate solution to my problem. I thank you for your feedback.

**Edit.** Please note that I do not take the downvotes personally, but I really care why you do disagree with me. Do you find that the answer received suits my requirements?

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't actually answer the question as posed: flag it as "not an answer". It might be moveable to a comment, otherwise it's screed that should be removed. Interesting screed, but screed nonetheless.

If it only partially answers the question, or forms the basis of what a complete answer would need: comment on it and ask for an expanded explanation of how the information helps to answer the question (as I see you have somewhat tried).